# Laravel default make:auth "login" route naming

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm learning about Laravel (5.6) built-in authentication using `make:auth` and digging around the generated routes, I noticed something on Laravel's route naming.

First of all, I found that these are the routes that are registered when using `make:auth`:

```
// Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
        $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

The first one, a `GET` route named `login`, will call `Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm` which renders the `auth.login` view.

And the second route, a no-name `POST` route, will call `Auth\LoginController@login` which retrieves the submitted data from the form and authenticates the user.

But when I looked at the generated `auth.login` view's form, its action is a `POST` request on route `login`.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
```

AFAIK, this form will call `Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm` instead of 
`Auth\LoginController@login` based on the defined route name on the form's `action` (which is `login`). But when the form is used, it will properly call `Auth\LoginController@login`. How is this possible?

Comment: These are two seperate requests. One is POST, the other is GET. So when the router detects a POST request, the login handler is invoked, otherwise, (when a GET request is detected) the login form is shown. If you run `php artisan route:list` from the command line this might be made more apparent to you.

Comment: @WebCode.ie but the invoked `POST` `login` route is not named. Does Laravel automatically detect other routes with the same `$uri`?

Comment: Yes, when the route is not named, the router dictates which controller/method to invoke based on a combination of the request method and uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `route` helper generates URLs. The URIs(paths) for those 2 routes are the same exact URI/path just registered for different HTTP methods.

So when you use that method you get a URL to `http://yoursite/login`. There is no implication of HTTP method here. That is up to the request being made to decide what method it uses. The URL is the URL regardless.

Request comes in and matches a URI, the request also will have a HTTP method. If it has HTTP method GET it hits the `get` route if it has HTTP method POST it hits the `post` route defined.

The URI isn't matched to the controller method. The URI and HTTP method together decide in this case.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I want to do the same thing, let's say I have 3 routes that will have the same URI but different HTTP method, I only need to name one of them because using the name with `route()` only serves as a mean to retrieve the URI. Is that right?

Comment: yea the URL helpers `route` `action` `url` etc only return a URL. In the case you are talking about since they all have the same URI, you could do that. The only issue is if you ever change those URIs or that name etc etc.  Laravel can get away with this because it is the Router that defines these, and they are defined together, there is no chance when registering the auth routes via the router that those URI will not match each other.